# How can I install grunt.js in node.js manually?

Tags: node.js, windows, gruntjs, npm, npm-install

Is it possible to install **grunt.js** manually in **node.js**.

Actually my support team downloaded the **grunt.js** for windows machine and place in my machine.

Due to my company proxy not able to install via node `npm install -g grunt-cli`.

So want to install the same form the downloaded package.

or we can install grunt.js without node.js?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/

Comment: Just a side note, what kind of company blocks npm to their developers?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's pretty easy to both install the module manually, just put it in `node_modules/grunt` or reference it directly `require('./path/to/grunt/directory')`, the real problem is that you also need to download [grunt's dependencies](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/package.json#L36) and their dependencies recursively.

```
└─┬ grunt@0.4.5
  ├── async@0.1.22
  ├── coffee-script@1.3.3
  ├── colors@0.6.2
  ├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
  ├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
  ├── exit@0.1.2
  ├─┬ findup-sync@0.1.3
  │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11
  │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │ │ └── minimatch@0.3.0
  │ └── lodash@2.4.2
  ├── getobject@0.1.0
  ├─┬ glob@3.1.21
  │ ├── graceful-fs@1.2.3
  │ └── inherits@1.0.2
  ├─┬ grunt-legacy-log@0.1.3
  │ ├─┬ grunt-legacy-log-utils@0.1.1
  │ │ ├── lodash@2.4.2
  │ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
  │ ├── lodash@2.4.2
  │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
  ├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
  ├── hooker@0.2.3
  ├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
  ├─┬ js-yaml@2.0.5
  │ ├─┬ argparse@0.1.16
  │ │ ├── underscore@1.7.0
  │ │ └── underscore.string@2.4.0
  │ └── esprima@1.0.4
  ├── lodash@0.9.2
  ├─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
  │ ├── lru-cache@2.7.3
  │ └── sigmund@1.0.1
  ├─┬ nopt@1.0.10
  │ └── abbrev@1.0.7
  ├── rimraf@2.2.8
  ├── underscore.string@2.2.1
  └── which@1.0.9
```

So either you have to install all these packages, or install them on another machine and copy them, or try to use a packer like browserify, webpack, or something else.